# Не получается работать с call()

Tags: javascript

Необходимо вывести значение поля name через 2 секунды после вызова метода, используя call().
Я начал делать так:

```
class Person {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

 writeName() {
    setTimeout.call(this, 
                    function(){
                        console.log(this.name)
                    }, 
                    2000);
  }

}

var pers = new Person("Alex");
pers.writeName();
```

Но этот вариант не работает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю имелось в виду реализовать одолжение метода, так :

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  writeName() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.name)
    }, 2000);
  }
}

var pers = new Person("Alex");
pers.writeName.call({
  name: 'test'
});
```

Comment: спасибо, но стрелочные использовать нельзя.

Comment: @Farad метод call не предназначен для этого